# How to add component in RSWAG request parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, openapi, rswag

I have some common parameters which are called in almost all API calls so is it possible to create component for those parameters and call them in rswag api request.

Something like `schema '$ref' => '#/definitions/parameters'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add in your `swagger_helper.rb`

Example:

```
# spec/swagger_helper.rb
config.swagger_docs = {
  'v1/swagger.json' => {
    swagger: '2.0',
    info: {
      title: 'API V1'
    },
    definitions: {
      errors_object: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          errors: { '$ref' => '#/definitions/errors_map' }
        }
      },
      errors_map: {
        type: 'object',
        additionalProperties: {
          type: 'array',
          items: { type: 'string' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# spec/integration/blogs_spec.rb
describe 'Blogs API' do

  path '/blogs' do

    post 'Creates a blog' do

      response 422, 'invalid request' do
        schema '$ref' => '#/definitions/errors_object'
  ...
end

# spec/integration/comments_spec.rb
describe 'Blogs API' do

  path '/blogs/{blog_id}/comments' do

    post 'Creates a comment' do

      response 422, 'invalid request' do
        schema '$ref' => '#/definitions/errors_object'
  ...
end
```

From: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/domaindrivendev/rswag#referenced-parameters-and-schema-definitions

Comment: The question asks for how to add definitions in common parameters, not in responses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your object in spec/swagger_helper.rb
Then in integration spec file define

```
path '/api/client/v0/blog' do
put 'Create a blog' do
  tags :Blog

  include_examples 'header_with_recognition_definitions'

  parameter name: :input_param, in: :body, schema: { '$ref' => '#/definitions/input_parameter_object' }

  response 200, 'blog was created successfully' do
    include_examples 'header_with_recognition_lets'
     ...
    run_test!
  end
end
```